# How to use .forEach to loop through and change things using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning how to use the DOM. I was trying to use .forEach (or a for loop, but would prefer .forEach) with a querySelectorAll("a") to cycle through each anchor and change what it says within the anchor. Like I would like the first Anchor to be called Services, the second one Product, etc... What I had been doing was something like this, which isn't a .forEach or a for loop:

```js
let navItems = document.querySelectorAll("a")

navItems[0].textContent = "Services"
navItems[1].textContent = "Product"
navItems[2].textContent = "Vision"
navItems[3].textContent = "Features"
navItems[4].textContent = "About"
navItems[5].textContent = "Contact"
```

This does what I want, however I just wanted to use .forEach to try to cycle through each nav item to change the name of each and I am having a hard time finding out how. I know there are many different ways to do this, but I am specifically looking to do it through .forEach or even just a regular for loop. I am trying to manipulate the HTML in this code:

```html
 <nav>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </nav>
```

to look like this if you look at the console:

```html
 <nav>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <a href="#">Product</a>
                <a href="#">Vision</a>
                <a href="#">Features</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </nav>
```

I hope I am phrasing this question right, this is my first time asking a question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd make an array of the *text content*s you need to assign instead, then iterate over them and access the `i`th element of the `navItems`:

```js
const texts = ['Services', 'Product', 'Vision', 'Features', 'About', 'Contact'];
const as = document.querySelectorAll('a');
texts.forEach((text, i) => {
  as[i].textContent = text;
});
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That helped out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As `forEach` iterates over an array, you should start of by an array of the values you want to inject.

Then you can use the second argument of `forEach` to point the index in the array, which should match the element's index.